# Lista Estática Sequencial

Tags: c, c++

Galera olhem este seguinte código :

`lista` é uma `struct`

```
lista * crialista()
{
    lista *li;

    li = (lista *) malloc(sizeof(struct lista));

    if(li !=NULL)
    {
        li->qtd = 0 ;
    }
}
```

porque foi alocado `lista` em `li` com `malloc` ? sendo que `li` foi declarado como `lista` , isso já não da acesso aos membros da minha `struct` `lista`?

Comment: `lista *li` define um **ponteiro**. Mas esse ponteiro não aponta para lado nenhum definido! Se preferires um objecto real, podes fazer `lista li` que é um objecto real com valores não incializados; com um ponteiro tens de o fazer apontar para algum sítio concreto (com `malloc()`) e depois atribuir valores aos elementos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quando você declarou `lista *li` você apenas disse que você vai ter um ponteiro do tipo lista. Seria o equivalente a dizer `int *i`. Esta última declaração não diz que você tem uma variável inteira, e você não pode armazenar valor nenhum em `i`, porque ele é um ponteiro e não um inteiro convencional. O mesmo vale para o tipo `lista`. O ponteiro `*li` não pode ter valores comuns, senão endereços, armazenados nele. Por isso é necessário alocar um espaço na memória, para guardar as informações na sua `struct` e então apontar para ela com o seu ponteiro `li`.